# IF and ELSE in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQRQg.jpg)

```
Value1   Value2    Color
2        16        =IF(A2>5,"Red", IF(AND(5>A2>1,40>B2>1,"Yellow")),IF(AND(5>A2>1,40>B2>60,"Red")),IF(AND(5>A2>1,60>B2>100,"Yellow")),"Green)
```

The logic for which, I believe is:

If "Value1" > 5 ---> "Red"

If "Value1" is between 1-5 and "Value2 " is between 1-40 ---> "Yellow"

If "Value1" is between 1-5 and "Value2 " is between 40-60 ---> "Red"

If "Value1" is between 1-5 and "Value2 " is between 60-100 ---> "Yellow"

Else ---> "Green"

I want the color «red», «yellow» og «green» to be shown in a column based on two values from two different colums. I’ve tried to look it up but I can’t find anything to make my formula work. Hope the picture explains

It only says that the formula is wrong but I can’t figure out what to do…

Comment: Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: It would be easier to help if you put the criteria in your post rather than in a picture of your computer screen.

Comment: Hi Martine, you've got `python` in your list of question tags, but I suspect you want an answer to cover a formula in excel that returns a text value based on the position of some input value in a range.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A2>5, "Red", IF(AND(A2>1, B2>1, B2<40), "Yellow", IF(AND(A2>1, B2>40, B2<60), "Red", IF(AND(A2>1, B2>60, B2<100), "Yellow", "Green"))))
```

or use this

```
=IF(OR(B2>=100, A2<=1), "Green", IF(OR(A2>5, 60>B2>40), "Red","Yellow"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=IF(AND(A2<=5,B2<100,B2>60),"Yellow",IF(OR(A2>5,AND(B2>=40,B2<60)),"Red","Green"))`

(Edited as I hadn't realised the mid-range for Value2 in 40-60 was to go red)

Rather than use (to me anyway) the confusing `1>x>100` way of expressing a range, I've instead put range boundaries as separate conditions within an `AND` clause. It's no better or worse, but I find it easier to parse that way.

Comment: Thank you, the logic you wrote is correct! But it didn’t work. And excel only says «there is a problem with this formula» so I can’t tell what doesn’t work

Comment: When i copy paste that formula into cell C2, with values 1 and 2 in cells A2, and B2, it gives me an answer.

Comment: You've got B2>39 and B2>60 in the same AND function. It would be easier to have the Yellow part be the Else result, I think.

Comment: Tried what you wrote @ThomasKimber and tried to change it with what you suggested Rory but none work…

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the feedback! And sorry for posting the question in a wrong «format», will do better next time.
The formula that worked for me in excel is: (i am writing this from my phone so sorry for any code block errors and such)

```
    =IF(A2>5; «Red»; IF(AND(1<A2;A2<5;1<B2;B2<40); «Yellow»; IF(AND(1<A2;A2<5;40<B2;B2<60); «Red»; IF(AND(1<A2;A2<5;60<B2;B2<100); «Yellow»; «Green»))))
```

Comment: Horrible! Why? Observe [this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RD4i7.png) which illustrates how your formula works. The purple color designates the rows containing suspicious results (in the resulting `C` column). For the most of it, you might say that it is the correct behavior but there is no way that `40` and `60` in column `B` should return `Green`. That being said, you also want to add some equal signs that will cover for some of the edge cases (`>=` or `<=`). Have a think and then accurately explain what should be returned in the suspicious (purple) cases or correct the formula yourself.

Comment: It has acutally worked fine so far for green and red. But does not work at all for yellow. I’ve tried and tried (and even chanhed to >=/<=) but doesn’t work… so if you have any idea on how I can get yellow to work I would like to hear:)

Comment: Many will exactly know what to do if you explain accurately what needs to be returned. You can start by telling us which values are wrong in the image I posted in my previous comment.